# Проблемы с меню на вордпресс, вдруг стало таким, до этого было нормальным

Tags: wordpress

Делаю сайт, ещё плохо разбираюсь во всем этом, может сама чего-то натыкала не то, помогите. Уже заново меню делала

Стало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. По картинкам лечат эстрасенсы, докторам же нужен пациент. 2. Учимся пользоваться инструментами вебмастера в браузере.